# proof with divisibility

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

this is the original question
prove:  $\forall c \in Z, a\neq 0 $and b both $ \in Z$
$a|b \iff c\cdot a|c\cdot b$

Then he corrected himself by saying for problem 1: to show that ca | cb implies a | b   ...   you must assume c NOT = 0 and invoke "Cancellation Property" of Z.

This kind of confused me can someone help me get started on this

Edit: I understand how to get to a|b now but how do I write this using formal proof logic?

Update: ok so this is what I've got
Prove: ∀c∈Z, c≠0 and b both∈Z a|b⇔ca|cb
a|b if and only if b=ak for some k∈Z
if and only if cb=cak for some c∈Z
if and only if ac|cb

Is this a valid proof? It seems kind of short and it's lacking the "cancelation property" but I'm not sure I understand how to write it any other way

Answer (score 2):

If you have that ca | cb thats like saying that $bc=caq$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ so, if $c\neq 0$ you can just take out those c in the both sides of the expression(because of "Cancellation Property" as he said) and you got left $b=aq$ wich means that $a|b$

Comment: oh wow! that's really obvious lol. How would I write that in a formal proof with an assumption and such?

Comment: No,  $\ j\mid k\ $ means $\,j\,$ divides $\,k,\,$ not $\,k\,$ divides $\,j,\,$ i.e. for some integer $\,i\,$ we have $\ ij = k,\ $ not  $\ j = ik.\ \ $

Comment: yes Bill, you are right i twisted the letters. Sorry

Comment: reflexive property of equality.. doesn't that not matter

Comment: oh i see the mistake thank you

Comment: @Mikky Order *does* matter for *divisibility*, e.g. $\,2\mid 4\,$ but not $\,4\mid 2.\ \ $